# Azure ML models - data transformation when making a prediction

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've trained a model in Azure ML Studio using Automated ML and now I want to use it to make predictions. But I don't know how should I prepare data for predictions. Should it be transformed or raw? There is a diagram of what transformation has been applied but no way to somehow export this transformation and apply in predictions
[image]

Comment: you can deploy it to endpoint and call for prediction.

Comment: ok but should I call with transformed data or raw?

Comment: you need to give the data on what columns you trained. Take some part of input data and select the column you trained and pass it to endpoint request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the dataset used to train, Having 12 columns.
My target column is **quality**, and trained on remaining
11 columns.

[image]

After training below is my model generated from automl.

[image]

Here, click on **Deploy** and select **Real Time Endpoint**.
You will get deployment configuration then click on more option.

[image]

Here, provide all required details in each tab which is highlighted
in the above image.
It takes some time to deploy.
After deployment you get as below in endpoint tab.
[image]

Here, you can see there is REST endpoint, which is used to make request with sample data.

You can also test it in the **Test** tab in your deployment.

[image]

In **Consume** tab you will find **Key** as below.
Copy any one of that.

[image]

Know you can make request.
I am using **Postman** to call  REST endpoint.
I am taking sample data of those 11 columns which are trained.

Add the copied key in **Authorization** field as below.

`Bearer <Your key>`

[image]

Then call with input data.
My input data for request is 11 columns as below.

```
{
    "Inputs": {
        "data": [
            {
                "fixed acidity": 7.8,
                "volatile acidity": 0.580,
                "citric acid": 0.02,
                "residual sugar": 2,
                "chlorides": 0.073,
                "free sulfur dioxide": 9,
                "total sulfur dioxide": 18,
                "density": 0.9968,
                "pH": 3.36,
                "sulphates": 0.57,
                "alcohol": 9.5
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In your case I believe it is 10 columns.
Give sample input data having 10 columns on what you have trained in body of the request as below.

Output:

[image]

If there is any transformation before the training on columns, then you need to transform the data for prediction. In Automated ml you can give directly the columns as above since you trained on them directly.